# Need help using the DC flag with intSliderGrp to control circle radius

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to have my slider directly change the radius of the created circle but I can't figure out the correct way to do it. The newRadius variable is the problem, in the function it's not technically created yet so throws error. I can't figure how to put the slider value into a variable and use DC flag to call it.

I'm still not great with Python for Maya so any help would be appreciated.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

result =0

testValue = 0

Test_Control_Radius= []

if cmds.window('Control 3', exists= True) :
    cmds.deleteUI('Control 3')

Mywindow = cmds.window('Control 3', t = "Quick Controls", w =50, h =100)

cmds.columnLayout()

cmds.rowColumnLayout( nc=1)

cmds.showWindow(Mywindow)

def createTestControl(testValue):
    if testValue < 1:
        
        global result
        
        global Test_Control_Radius
        
        Test_Control_Radius = cmds.circle(n="Test_Control", ch=False)
        
        myScaleX= cmds.getAttr('Test_Control.scaleX') #added
        
        myScaleY= cmds.getAttr('Test_Control.scaleY')  #added
        
        myScalZe= cmds.getAttr('Test_Control.scaleZ')  #added
        
        cmds.connectControl(TestRadius,myScaleX)     #added
        
        result = testValue + 1
       
        return result
    else:
        cmds.delete(Test_Control_Radius[0])
        
        Test_Control_Radius = cmds.circle(n="Test_Control", ch=False)
        
        testValue +=1
    
        return result
       
#def  attachRadius():
#    
#    TestRadius = cmds.intSliderGrp(newRadius, q=True, value=True)  ##### #line B
#    
#    cmds.setAttr('Test_Control.scaleX', TestRadius)   ####  LINE C
#    
#    cmds.setAttr('Test_Control.scaleY', TestRadius)   ####  LINE C 
#    
#    cmds.setAttr('Test_Control.scaleZ', TestRadius)   ####  LINE C
      
 
cmds.text('Instructions 1', l = 'Step 1: Create Test Control')
cmds.separator('First Speerator', w = 50, h= 15)        
cmds.button (l= "Create Test Control", c= "createTestControl(result)")

cmds.separator('Second Speerator', w = 50, h= 15)  
cmds.text('Instructions 2', l = 'Step 2: Pick Desired radius of Controls')
cmds.separator('Third Speerator', w = 50, h= 15) 

newRadius = cmds.intSliderGrp(l="Radius", min = -1000, max = 1000,value=0, field= True, dc=attachRadius())         ##########  LINE A
#TestRadius = cmds.intSliderGrp(newRadius, q=True, value=True)        #####################  

cmds.separator('Fourth Speerator', w = 50, h= 15)
cmds.text('Instructions 3', l = 'Step 3: Click on Top Joint then Click Assimilate Button')
cmds.separator('Fitth Speerator', w = 50, h= 15)
```

Comment: If you want to control an attribute directly with a slider, it could be helpful to look at the connectControl command.

Comment: @haggikrey I've tried using the connectControl like suggested but getting an boject not found that I don't understand. I've compared it to similar examples and not sure why this error comes up. I updated my changes. the rror is # Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 67: connectControl: Object '0' not found. #

Comment: There is no variable or somthing like that called "TestRadius", so the connectControl fails.